# При отработке BeautifulSoup выскакивает ошибка и программа не выполняется

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Имеется следующая программа.

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
   print(tag.get('href', None))
```

При выполнении программы выскакивает ошибка. Проблема возникает в файле BeautifulSoup.py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ZTL\Desktop\Python-write\Py4inf\paranorm\urlparanorm.py", line 2, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import *
  File "C:\Users\ZTL\Desktop\Python-write\Py4inf\paranorm\BeautifulSoup.py", line 448
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Если я правильно понял, библиотека не может импортироваться из-за синтаксической ошибки в коде? Как решить данную проблему, и является ли это проблемой, а не просто ошибкой в самом файле?

Это учебный файл и другие люди выполняют данное задание без проблем, качая фаил с [данной страницы](http://www.py4inf.com/code/BeautifulSoup.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Причины ошибки:

Вы столкнулись с различиями между версиями Python 2.x и Python 3.x. Дело в том, что синтаксис `raise` в Python 2.x:

```
raise E, V
```

Был изменен в Python 3.x на:

```
raise E(V)
```

### Что делать?

По всей видимости, Вы скопировали файл `BeautifulSoup.py` в директорию с Вашим скриптом. Данный способ не является традиционным способом распространения библиотек для Python. Вместо этого, вам стоит воспользоваться менеджером пакетов [`pip`](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#basic-usage):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Кроме того, Вы можете просто сменить версию Python на 2.x. Тем не менее, Вам все равно стоит обратить внимание на распространение пакетов - это сбережет Ваше время в будущем.

Comment: Подскажите, где должен храниться пакет BeautifulSoup4? В какой директории? Чтобы его можно было открыть посредством менеджера пакетов pip.

Comment: Его не нужно открывать менеджером пакетов, `pip` самостоятельно скачает его из репозитория. Просто напишите `pip install beautifulsoup4` в консоли. Если у Вас Python >= 2.7.9, то `pip` идет в комплекте, и Вы можете написать `python.exe -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Спасибо! Отличная автоматизация процесса. Так намного удобнее.